# What is the difference between Hubble Function and Hubble Parameter?

Tags: cosmology

I've seen the terms **Hubble Function** and **Hubble Parameter** used - apparently - interchangeably.  The older documents seem to favor **Hubble Parameter** while the newer ones (IMO) seem to use **Hubble Function**.  Is there a difference and is there a preference?

Comment: Theres a difference between Hubble Constant and Hubble Parameter/Function but I dont think theres difference between Parameter and Functions terms. They mean the same thing; Hubble constant changes with time

Comment: **Hubble constant changes with time** Yes, I've heard the same about the vacuum energy constant.  It would appear that constants aren't what they used to be.

Comment: Vacuum energy changes in some theories. But in general we take it as a constant. More formally the Hubble function is $H(t)$ meanwhile Hubble constant is $H(t=t_0) = H_0$ for $a(t_0)=1$.

Comment: @GluonSoup “*constants aren't what they used to be*” - This is incorrect. The Hubble parameter is **always constant** over space and is (at least approximately) a reciprocal of the age of the universe, so it is **always a function** of time. For example, a galaxy receding away from us at some speed will always recede at the same speed (ignoring acceleration, if any). The Hubble parameter for this galaxy is constantly changing in time in such a way that the speed always remains the same.